# Can I write a macro to block other macros?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with an Excel document that I'm trying to add protection to. Unfortunately, there are very simple macros that can be run to remove the standard password protection. Is there a way I can add a macro to the workbook that blocks other macros from running? Like, on event that another macro runs, give a msg and exit the other macro?

Comment: Not really. The only solution that I've come up with in the past is to store the sensitive data in a more secure DB which is separate from the workbook. When the workbook was opened the user would get a form to connect to the DB with. If they didn't know the location, user name, and password, then they could not get access to the sensitive data, as nothing was ever saved into the workbook itself. Plus as a little safety protocol, if invalid information was entered 10 times in a row, the workbook would completely wipe itself. Hope this helps!

Comment: change the file permissions maybe so that only trusted people can access the file? I dont think macro's can access / open a file without proper read/write permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is, **No**.

The expanded, convoluted answer is, **theorhetically** you could fire code at regular intervals that will intercept any current process.  But, it will slow your worksheet down because you'd have to fire it off every few seconds for it to be effective, and you would have to determine somehow whether the process intercepted was "authorized".  That's a lot of scripting and a lot of logic dedicated to the off-chance that one of your users has malicious intent.

Comment: And the user can always disable your "blocking" code by not enabling macros when they open the document...